# Running a function with a non-existing optional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameter-passing

I have create a function which has an optional argument `y` on it:

```
def f(x, *y):
    print(x)
    if y in locals():
    print(y)
```

When passing these `x` and `y`arguments to the function it only ouputs `x` even though `y` is in the local variables:

```
a = ['String', 'Optional String']
x = a[0]
if len(a) == 2:
    y = a[1]

f(x, *y) #Output: String
```

I have a second issue that when giving only the `x` argument and not the `y` it ouputs a NameError:

```
a = ['String', 'Optional String']
x = a[0]
if len(a) == 2:
    y = a[1]

f(x, *y) #Output: NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

How can I get this working? Thanks in advance.

#### EDIT:

Looks like I misunderstood what an optional argument was. Ended up changing the whole code and its Fixed. These answers helped me anyways, Thank you.

Comment: `y` *isn't* optional within the function; it will always be defined, and will contain zero or more positional arguments. `y in locals()` is therefore totally pointless. Why don't you just call `f(*a)` to unpack the elements to arguments?

Comment: An optional argument is one with a default value like `def f(x, y=None):`

Comment: `y in locals()` doesn't check what you expect it to check. It looks to see if the *value* of `y` exists in the dictionary returned by `locals()`. It never will because `y` will be a tuple (possibly empty), and the keys of the dictionary will all be identifiers (strings). You probably meant `if "y" in locals()`, which will always be true (since `y` is always defined, even if its value is an empty tuple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to check if y is a local name would be `if 'y' in locals():`.

However, that would always be true, because `y` is always a local name, even if `f` is called with only one argument. In which case we have `y == ()`, i.e. `y` is an empty tuple.

You can simply write `if y:` if you want to know if there was more than one argument.

```
def f(x, *y):
    print(x)
    if y:
        print(y)
```

I can't confirm your second problem. While it doesn't do what you probably want, there is no NameError. (You probably want to drop the asterisk.)

Oh, and if you want optional arguments, use optional arguments. Not variable length arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The output of locals is a dictionary - in your function if you were to do:

```
def f(x, *y):
    print(locals())

f('string', 'other string')
```

The output would be

```
{'y': ('other string',), 'x': 'string'}
```

So to access the values within y, you would call it like so:

```
def f(x, *y):
    print(x)
    if 'y' in locals():
        print(y)
f('string', 'other string')
```

Output:

```
string
other string
```